# Core Data NSFetchRequest returns unsorted array after deleting object and refetching data

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have a Core Data database built using a UIManagedDocument that I load into a `UITableView` and also plot certain points of that data on a graph. I find that when I add an object to the database or delete an object from the database and then fetch the data, the array that `NSFetchRequest` returns is not sorted, even though I have a sort descriptor in the request. The interesting part is that if I wait a few seconds and then fetch/refetch the data, it now comes back sorted. I think I must be doing something wrong. Is there some kind of callback I should be using from Core Data to know that the database change was completed? It's strange because all the data is always in the database, just not sorted. I'm not super experienced with it, so I'm not sure.

Here's the code from my fetch request:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"FuelPurchase"];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"dateTimeStamp" ascending:YES];
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

NSError *error = nil;
[self.fuelPurchaseDatabase.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Comment: Try saving the context between deletion and re-fetch.

Comment: I am saving right after the deletion call in my commitEditingStyle: method. I have found that if I add an object to the database and try and graph it too quickly, the same problem happens where it's not sorted.

Comment: Do you reuse the `NSFetchRequest` object when re-fetching? It looks like a caching issue.

Comment: I am creating a new NSFetchRequest every time. I don't have a property for it if that's what you mean.

Comment: Can you post the code where you configure the fetch request?

Comment: Ok. I've put the code up in my original post. Thanks...

Comment: Are you sure it's not a quirk of the `NSFetchResultsController`? The fetch request itself seems too simple to trigger a bug in Core Data.

Comment: Yes, because my graph data is not using NSFetchedResultsController and the problem is there too. I am using UIManagedDocument to support my Core Data database. Not sure if that could be an issue.

Comment: As an added note I filed this as a bug with Apple, and they contacted me to ask for a sample application showing the problem. I sent one over and they said they would be having a look into it!

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem (except insertion instead of deletion). Have you heard back from Apple yet?

Comment: @Scott Yes I just heard back about a week ago. The bug has been addressed in iOS 6.0! Wow, never had that happen before. Plus I never expected to hear feedback from them. Very impressed.

Comment: That's good news! The bug will still be present in iOS 5, though, right? Or is it somehow fixed in earlier iOS versions as well?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `controllerDidChangeContent:` callback?

Maybe use this to update your view instead of doing it procedurally after you save your context.

Comment: I can try this, but also if I add an object to the database before even setting up a FetchedResultsController (in a different view) and load the table and graph too quickly, it is also not sorted.